# Using GTKMM with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gtkmm

I want to use GTKMM with Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10. I installed GTKMM through MSYS2 following [these instructions](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gtkmm/MSWindows). This installed GTKMM and all its requirements. I created the project in visual studio and added the directory that gtkmm.h was in to the Additional Include Directories.

However, gtkmm.h couldn't find the headers it was including, and I'd have to add their directories. It doesn't take long to realise that the MSYS2 directory structure doesn't work for Visual Studio and there'll be a LOT more directories to add. It's going to be a pita to do it this way every time I create a new GTKMM project.

I've looked at [this page](https://wiki.gnome.org/Attic/GtkmmOnWindows) but the installers it links only go up to 2.22.
[This one](https://gtkmm-installation.blogspot.com/) links to a [github](https://github.com/codekiddy2/Visual-Studio-gtkmm) with Visual Studio projects that are out of date (last commit was in 2016). It also links to [this guide](https://github.com/codekiddy2/Visual-Studio-gtkmm/wiki) whose [Preparation page](https://github.com/codekiddy2/Visual-Studio-gtkmm/wiki/Preparation) says that Visual Studio 2015 *Enterprise* Edition is needed. It says you don't need Enterprise edition if you create your own 'master solution' but doesn't cover that process.

What I'm looking for are clear instructions (for dummies) on how to get a current version GTKMM set up with Visual Studio. I want to do everthing from Visual Studio including managing the project, editing the files, and compilation.

Comment: Its in `vcpkg` here: [https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/tree/master/ports/gtkmm](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/tree/master/ports/gtkmm) this may be the simplest way to use with Visual Studio.

Comment: Didn't know about vcpkg. I've got it working now. Thankyou. You should make this an answer to the question so I can accept it.

Comment: Although I should say that debug builds throw a 'Memory Access Violation' exception. Release bulids work fine.

Comment: At the moment I can't easily test. I use `vcpkg` in production code but know the updated ports will break my production there is an ongoing bug report for the combination of vtk + Qt since last November. I would have to set git back to where it is currently after testing.